# Intersect dataframes that have a List column

Tags: apache-spark

I have two dataframes that have List as a column. Both the dataframes are identical except for the fact that the order of the list is different in the dataframes.
eg. Schema: (id text, name List'<'text>)
df1: (5,WrappedArray(abc, pqr, xyz))
df2: (5,WrappedArray(abc, xyz, pqr))
When i use intersect i dont get this record in the results. How can i get the intersection of such records?

Comment: As an alternative, is there a way to sort the list in the data-frame?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right that the easiest way would be to sort the list column.

```
val sortListFunc = udf((inputList: WrappedArray[String]) => {
    inputList.sorted
})

val df1Sorted = df1
   .withColumn("name_sorted",sortListFunc(col("name"))
   .select($"id","name_sorted".as("name"))

val df2Sorted = df2
   .withColumn("name_sorted",sortListFunc(col("name"))
   .select($"id","name_sorted".as("name"))
```

Then you should be able to join or intersect.